# Saving data to a json file using python

Tags: python

I have JSON data stored in a file (**Movies.json**). i want to read the file and do some process and then save the output in new file

```
with open("Movies.json",'r') as f:
        movies = json.loads(f.read())
        // doing some process
```

How can i save the output?

Currently, I am trying this but it's not working:

```
json.dump(movies, f)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for output you need to use 'w' instead of 'r'

```
import json 
# Opening JSON file
f = open('movies.json')

# returns JSON object as
# a dictionary
movies = json.load(f)

# Iterating through the json
# list
for i in movies:
    print(i['id'])
 
# output 
with open("Movies.json", 'w') as f:
    json.dump(movies, f)
    
# Closing file
f.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using 'r' it is for reading, you should use 'w'

```
import json 
with open("Movies.json", 'w') as f:
    json.dump(movies, f)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to let the file be closed and then reopen it for write and write the modified object back again:

```py
with open("Movies.json", 'w') as f:
    json.dump(movies, f)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open("Movies.json",'r') as rf:
    with open("New_Movies.json",'w') as wf:
          movies = json.loads(rf.read())
          #doing some process
          movies_after_process = do_something(movies)
          wf.write(json.dumps(movies_after_process))
```